# Call a function from a string in JS

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I have an array of strings that I wish to use as callbacks, but the below code is not working.

When running the function, I'm getting the error `TypeError: fn is not a function` logged when `callback_array` contains only `update_front_page_images`.

`callback_array` currently only contains 1 element (`update_front_page_images`), which is the name of a function I wish to run.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
function run_reset_callbacks(callback_array){

    for(var key in callback_array){

        try {
            fn = window[callback_array[key]];
            fn();
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log('Function \''+callback_array[key]+'\' does not exist. '+err);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of storing function names, why not store references to functions? You can do this in JS, since functions are objects. That is instead of `callback_array = ['update_front_page_images']` just `callback_array = [update_front_page_images]`. Also, don't use a `for...in` to loop over arrays. Use `forEach` or a vanilla `for` loop.

Comment: Can you show us a complete example?

Comment: @MattBall. Thanks for you reply. `'update_front_page_images'` (as with any others I may need to add) is declared via PHP and output using `json_encode()`, so I'm unsure how to declare it as a reference at this point. Is there a way of making the value a reference when I pick it out of the JSON object and place it into `callback_array`?

Comment: Wait: is `update_front_page_images` a JavaScript function, or a PHP function? If it's the latter, how do you expect to be able to call it via JavaScript?

Comment: @MattBall. I've updated my code now, making it so that I pass references to functions (`callback_array = [update_front_page_images];`). My question now though, is how do I call that as a function?? Thanks.

Comment: `callback_array[0]()` will call `update_front_page_images`.

Comment: That simple... Didn't even think to try that, thanks muchly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're defining your functions in a way that you can call them as window[] if you want to use this model. You need to define your functions as variables on the window object. A standard function definition will fail.

http://jsfiddle.net/HpXYM/2/

```
//Works
window.hello = function () {
  alert("hello");
};

//Works    
test = function () {
  alert("test");
};

//Fails
function fail() {
  alert("fail")
};
```

This should solve the problem if you are set on this method but I would recommend you follow Matt Ball's advice.

Comment: Thank you. This helps for now. I'm certainly interested in learning a more efficient method, but that is for another day...

Answer (score 0):

Change your Scope! I think you are not able to access `window`:

[**JS Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/3Q9pS/)

```
var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');

// Wrong
var cbArray = ['update_front_page_images', 'dummyFunction']; // Array created from PHP

function update_front_page_images() {
    outputDiv.innerHTML = outputDiv.innerHTML+ '<br/>' + 'Called me? I am "update_front_page_images" !!';
}

function dummyFunction() {
    outputDiv.innerHTML = outputDiv.innerHTML+ '<br/>' + 'Called me? I am "" !!';
}
// -- Wrong


// Right
var cbArray = {
    'update_front_page_images': function() {
        outputDiv.innerHTML = outputDiv.innerHTML+ '<br/>' + 'Called me? I am "update_front_page_images" !!';
    },
    'dummyFunction': function() {
        outputDiv.innerHTML = outputDiv.innerHTML+ '<br/>' + 'Called me? I am "dummyFunction" !!';
    }
}
// -- Right

// your Code
function run_reset_callbacks(callback_array){

    for(var key in callback_array){

        try {
            fn = window[callback_array[key]]; // Wrong
            fn = callback_array[key]; // Right
            fn();
        }
        catch(err) {
            outputDiv.innerHTML = 'Function \''+callback_array[key]+'\' does not exist. '+err;
        }
    }

}

run_reset_callbacks(cbArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Arrays should be enumerated with an indexed loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < callback_array.length; i++) { ...  }
```

If `callback_array` is really a literal object, the approach above is fine, but it would be safer to check for `hasOwnProperty` before evaluating the property.

```
if(callback_array.hasOwnProperty(key)) { ... } // use it
```

Otherwise, make sure that `update_front_page_images` is within the global scope and ready for evaluation at the time this function is called.